# Is it possible to add a facebook 'like' button to a website without the numer of 'likes'?

Tags: facebook

I'm pretty sure this used to be possible, but there doesn't seem to be an option any more.  Is there any way to do it?

Comment: Did you checked these two links: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2950172/facebook-like-button-hide-count and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4989173/need-facebook-like-button-without-count ?

Answer (score 5):

For some reason facebook has decided not to allow the like count to be hidden, but with a little CSS magic you can come close. Just but a div block on top of the like count having the same color as the background. For an example, see http://warpdrivesoftware.com

Add a facebook_hide_count div after your button:

```
<div class="fb-like" data-href="http://warpdrivesoftware.com" data-send="false" data-layout="button_count" data-show-faces="false"></div>
<div class="facebook_hide_count"></div>
```

And add this to your CSS file:

```
.facebook {
position: relative;
width: 46px;
height: 21px;
}

.facebook_hide_count {
width: 100px;
height: 21px;
background: white;
position: absolute;
left: 46px;
top: 0;
}
```

Naturally, this only works if your like button is in English. If not, simply adjust the pixel count to whatever fits your locale.

Answer (score 3):

You can hide the number of likes by using setting the dimensions of the like button to be smaller then its content. That will in effect hide the total.

Example:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.example.com/" show_faces="false" width="450"></fb:like>
```

could be changed to this:

```
<script src="http://connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1"></script><fb:like href="http://www.divorcemyteam.com/" show_faces="false" width="100"></fb:like>
```

That should cut off the count of likes for that page.

Answer (score 0):

You could do it with `fb:like:layout="button"` and avoid the need to use `.css` all together. Learn more by reading Facebook's API on their *Like* button.